# Do groupby statements cause dataframes to collapse to series?

Tags: python, pandas

I started with a large dataframe. I pared and rearranged some columns. The head of the last (rather large) dataframe I saved looked like this:

```
# bsa_mod = 'best supporting actress modified' dataframe
[1] bsa_mod = bsa_mod[['Year', 'Name', 'Winner']]
[2] bsa_mod.head()

    Year    Name              Winner
431 1936    Beulah Bondi        0.0
432 1936    Alice Brady         0.0
433 1936    Bonita Granville    0.0
434 1936    Maria Ouspenskaya   0.0
435 1936    Gale Sondergaard    1.0
```

I needed to group all of the names together and count the dummy variables next to each. For example, Agnes Morehead appears in the Name column 4 times and has either a 0 or 1 next to her name each time, so the final summary table should say 'Agnes Morehead 4'. I got that with the following:

```
# aggregate nominations by actress
bsa_mod_count = bsa_mod.groupby('Name').Winner.count()
Name
Abigail Breslin    1
Adriana Barraza    1
Agnes Moorehead    4
Alfre Woodard      1
Alice Brady        2
Name: Winner, dtype: int64
```

I ran .describe() on this to get summary stats and found that the max value calculated was 6.

I wanted to find out who this mystery person was by running something like:

```
most_nominations = bsa_mod_count[bsa_mod_count.Winner == 6]
```

Much to my surprise, I got an attribute error saying that 'Winner' did not exist and that the data type with which I was now dealing was a series and no longer a dataframe.

Do dataframes degenerate to a series after a 'groupby'? I wasn't expecting my index to be overwritten, which also seemed to happen when I ran .agg(['count']). Is there another way I could have done this, so as to preserve my dataframe and render that '6' useable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#if you want to retain the index and the dataframe format, try below:
bsa_mod['Winner_Count'] = bsa_mod.apply(lambda x: bsa_mod.Name.value_counts()[x.Name],axis=1)
print(bsa_mod)

     Year               Name  Winner  Winner_Count
431  1936       Beulah Bondi     0.0             1
432  1936        Alice Brady     0.0             1
433  1936   Bonita Granville     0.0             1
434  1936  Maria Ouspenskaya     0.0             1
435  1936   Gale Sondergaard     1.0             1

#Then you can do something like:
bsa_mod[bsa_mod.Winner_Count == 2]
```

Comment: That is a very sexy lambda function. I'll definitely play around with it. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer. If you don't mind me asking, how is it that your way manages to retain the index and the other way does not? And how do I interpret [x.Name]?

Comment: Because when you do a groupby, you are doing an aggregation operation, which could reduce the number of records. If you have multiple 'Alice Brady' for example, after groupby, there will be only one record for 'Alice Brady'. It'll be ambiguous to use the original index as there are multiple of them. While in my solution, I'm not doing group by at all. The apply function will only find the count of the name in the current row.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is No, group by does preserve the structure.

in your example `bsa_mod.groupby('Name').Winner.count()` returns a series object whereas `bsa_mod.groupby('Name').count()` returns a data frame.

Comment: Asked and answered! Wish that had been in the video I watched. Many thanks!